# Confused with virtual environments in python django

Tags: python, django, centos

I have my Django project folder and inside that i have my `virtualenv` folder

I have few questions

1. I have packages already installed in main installation and as well in virtual env. Dont those packages mix with each other. I mean if i have old version in main installation and new version in virtual env how does the system knows which one to choose
2. Suppose i move my project folder to new computer than can i use same virtual env folder because it was in the same app directory or i have to start all over again
3. How will i know that pip install package to virtual env or main installation

Comment: I think your problem is you may confuse which package use in which state. You can avoid this problem by use `--no-site-packages` when you setup virtual environment that will not include anything from your default site pacakge to your virtual environment.

Comment: I mean to say that if i use s system pacakges then will those gets install within virtualenv or virtual env uses it from main system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unless you created the virtualenv with --system-site-packages, packages don't mix at all. If they did, Virtualenv has priority.
2. If the path doesn't change, there are chances that you can reuse it. You could [make a virtualenv --relocatable](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/1.6.1/index.html#making-environments-relocatable) if the path changes. But you should make a requirements file and be able to regenerate a fresh virtualenv in one `pip -r req.txt` command.
3. If a virtualenv is activated, pip will install in the virtualenv, it has priority.

Comment: Thanks. I unserstand 2 and 3 but still don't quite get point 1. what will ahppen with that site packages option. Is there any way not to use evena single package from main installation. i mean is it possible that main insttllation has 0 packages and my whole project depend upon the virtual env only.

Comment: Use the `--no-site-packages` option.

Comment: @Ohad: `--no-site-packages` is default nowadays. With `--no-site-packages`, the virtualenv will not give access to system site-packages. With `--system-site-packages`, virtualenv will enable system site-packages when the virtualenv is activated. You can run `pip freeze` to see the list of installed packages, and remove those you don't want with `pip uninstall`.

Comment: If i use no site packages then will the system dont use any of system pacakges or script will use system pacakges but they won't be in virtual env. because  i think thos pacakges PYTHON PATH , will still be there. i mean if i have PIL package in system and not in virtual env. will my system get it from Main or it will give error

Comment: Are you reading my answers ? **It doesn't matter if you use --no-site-packages because it is enabled by default**. **Use `pip freeze` to figure what packages are in your env**. Unless you use --system-site-packages, then your virtualenv will not have access to the PIL installed in your system site-packages - obviously ? Also, I should note that virtualenv creates empty envs by default, if in doubt just check the files in a fresh test venv - vens should not be different depending on the system installed packages.